# Mass-Assignment Error with Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

I am having trouble getting the "accepts_nested_attributes_for :people"
 to work. The goal is for the user (called "Person" in my app) to be able to establish a family name upon signup. Family is on a separate table from person. I've read through lots of stack overflow posts on this but none of the solutions seem to be working. The reoccurring theme with this error is forgetting to add :people_attributes to the attr_accessible. I believe I have done this correctly. I may be forgetting something in the controller.

I have a one-to-many relationship with Family to Person

Here is my relevant code:

Family Model:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :people_attributes

  has_many :adventures
  has_many :people

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people

end
```

Person Model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :first_name, :last_name, :nickname, :family_id, :password, :password_confirmation

  belongs_to :family
  has_many :reviews


  has_secure_password
end
```

Family View

```
<%= form_for(@family) do |f| %>
 <% if @family.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@family.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this family from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
     <% @family.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<table>
 <tr>
      <td class="form-cell"><%= f.label :name %></td>
      <td class="form-cell"><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="form-cell"><%= f.fields_for :person do |ts| %></td>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.label :first_name %></td>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.text_field :first_name %></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.label :last_name %></td>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.text_field :last_name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.label :age %></td>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.text_field :age %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.label :nickname %></td>
        <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.text_field :nickname %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.label :password %></td>
       <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.password_field :password %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.label :password_confirmation %></td>
       <td class="form-cell"><%= ts.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
 <%= f.submit %>
```

Below is my Full Trace from my Development log

```
    activemodel (3.2.12) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
    activemodel (3.2.12) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
    activemodel (3.2.12) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
    activemodel (3.2.12) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
    activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
    activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
    app/controllers/families_controller.rb:43:in `new'
    app/controllers/families_controller.rb:43:in `create'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__4160186070491300860__process_action__2492885545127699891__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
    activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
    journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
    journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
    journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
    activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
    activerecord (3.2.12) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__555282021550517493__call__927558071375684288__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
    railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
    railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
    railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
    railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    /Users/mikeland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
    /Users/mikeland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
    /Users/mikeland/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Post up the full stack trace of the error from your development.log file please

Comment: just posted, thanks JamesW

Comment: @Robin has just posted the correct answer.

Comment: You missed the essential part of the stack trace (The params and the error message) The params would have told you EXACTLY what you had wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another theme with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is people writing this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :person do |ts| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= f.fields_for :people do |ts| %>
```

If you pass `:person` in `fields_for`, then rails is going to be looking for `person_attributes`.

And you'll need to build a person in the controller: `@family.people.build`. The same way you build a new @family record to display the form, you need to build a person record belonging to the family to display the nested section.

Comment: When I change
    <%= f.fields_for :person do |ts| %>
To
    <%= f.fields_for :people do |ts| %>
it causes my nested section of the form to disappear completely.

Comment: It's because you did not build the association properly. Have you done this? `@family.people.build`

Comment: Working Thank You so much. BTW - I created a Git Repo as an example of creating Rails Forms with Nested Attributes. 
https://github.com/lando2319/example_of_rails_form_with_nested_attributes